Deploying ROS 1 based Autoware with ROS 2 simulator
I want to run the ROS 1 based self-driving Autoware stack (https://github.com/UT-ADL/autoware_mini) in the ROS 2 based simulator (AWSIM labs). I am wondering if someone had tried something similar and could share the experience or at least some guide? My idea is to use the ros1 bridge. However I am not sure how to proceed with the custom message translation between ROS 1 and ROS 2.
